# Does the noun "structure" require an article in this case?

Tags: nouns, syntactic-analysis, articles, determiners

Can I write "Structure is key to the clarity of writing" without a determiner before "structure"?

Comment: I would write it in a different way, "Structure is the key to clarity of writing."

Comment: Use *in* instead of *of* and it will sound more idiomatic: "Structure is the key to clarity in writing." No article needed.

Answer (score 0):

*Structure* without an article is fine since you are talking about something in general. For the same reason, you should also use *clarity* without an article, as both comments above suggest:

*Structure is key to clarity in writing.*

I suppose that you are using *key* as an adjective here, meaning

adj.
Of crucial importance; significant: key decisions; the key element of the thesis.

Such usage exists as in the following example:

*Maybe you could accuse the film of being scattershot or episodic, but its piecemeal structure is key to its virtues.*

However, it may be confusing, so you could consider using a noun after it: "a key factor".

[ludwig.guru](https://ludwig.guru/s/structure+is+key)

[thefreedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/key)